# Web3 js and frontend frameworks

Tags: web3js, dapps

Will i need a front end framework like React, while using web3 to build Decentralized Applications?

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever tools you wish on the frontend to interact with Ethereum: vanilla JavaScript, Angular, React, Vue, etc. Ethereum itself is programming language and framework neutral. You can call smart contracts from both frontend and backend.

[Here is an example for vanilla JavaScript](https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal-vanilla-js-example).